# Bash script - Printf doesn't add a new line after each output

Tags: bash, printf

I am trying to use getent to print passwd file for a specified user and want to get a specific output like this (jumping lines included):

```
User: <username> 
UID: <user_uid> 
Groups: <group 1> <group 2> <group 3>
Home folder: <user's_home_folder>
```

So I am using this but can't seem to get it right:

```
getent passwd foo | awk -F ':' '{printf "%s\n" "User: "$1, "UID: "$3, "Groups: "$4, "Home folder: "$6}'
```

Am I doing `printf` wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [correct way](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html):

```
getent passwd foo| awk -F ':' '{printf "User: %s\nUID: %s\nGroups: %s\nHome folder: %s\n", $1, $3, $4, $6}'
```